# How to get selected file's path in "<input type="file">" in jquery?

Tags: jquery, dom

When i a selecting a file i need to get full path of the file like

`"file:///C:/Users/prabhuvignesh/Desktop/sample.jpg"` this.

is this possible by using jquery?

`$("#ID").val();` gives file name and i need fill path along with all attribute like size, extension, etc..!

i need this for cordova plugin called "filetransfer"
where

```
var win = function (r) {
    console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode);
    console.log("Response = " + r.response);
    console.log("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
}

var fail = function (error) {
    alert("An error has occurred: Code = " + error.code);
    console.log("upload error source " + error.source);
    console.log("upload error target " + error.target);
}

var options = new FileUploadOptions();
options.fileKey = "file";
options.fileName = fileURL.substr(fileURL.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
options.mimeType = "text/plain";

var params = {};
params.value1 = "test";
params.value2 = "param";

options.params = params;

var ft = new FileTransfer();
ft.upload(fileURL, encodeURI("http://some.server.com/upload.php"), win, fail, options);
```

this needs file path (fileURL), so how can i get it..?
any alternate approaches are also welcome.

Comment: you can not do that. browser will prevent this for security reasons.

Comment: You may find this answer helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201071/how-to-get-full-path-of-selected-file-on-change-of-input-type-file-using-jav

Comment: @MilindAnantwar as i mentioned in edited part i need it for purpose and what to do in that case?

Comment: @chxzy i want full path of it not only a file name as i mentioned

Comment: @RajagopalPG I clearly understand your requirement, and if you have read the link above you will see it is **NOT** possible to get full file path via JavaScript for security.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only get the local name of user selected file in an HTML file input element using the [File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/name).

> For security reasons, the path is excluded from this property.

Comment: For my cordova function i need file path and for that what should i do..?

Comment: Why do you need the path? File content and and some meta information is provided, you can process on server side.

Comment: you mean like `document.getElementById("myfileinputID").files` will be enough to get it uploaded?

Comment: No. If that input is wrapped in a form with correct `enctype` attribute value and submitted to a server side script, then it will be uploaded and processing can take place in the script.